# Communicate between Shell and PHP?

Tags: php, shell, debian, exec, wget

im going to write a php script that should do the following:

- create user
- check for, download and install packages
- download files with wget
- move files
- set permissions
- start applications with screen
- stop screen session

i don't want to use default www-data user for that - how can i exec the cmd with another user?

Whats the best way to do that with PHP on Debian/Ubuntu ?

Maybe run a .sh file (+ params) with `shell_exec()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon your need you can use `.sh` as well `exec` too

If you have lots of commands under single action then you should prefer **shell script**

For one liners `shell_exec` works efficiently.

For more reference (regarding syntax) visit [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: thanks! whats the best way to run commands as another user(not www-data e.x.)?

Comment: You will need to do chmod 777 on your specific folder / file. because that command is going to be executed as 'other user group'

Comment: You can do it with jQuery as well. [refer this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15264/executing-a-shell-command-from-php-with-shell-exec)